# Select MySQL records from multiple tables and sorting

Tags: php, mysql

Having one heck of a time with this one.... I have the following simplified tables

```
+---------+   +-------------+   +-------------+
| fields  |   | details     |   | customers   |
+---------+   +-------------+   +-------------+
| id      |   | customer_ID |   | customer_ID |
| caption |   | field_id    |   | progress    |
+---------+   | field_value |   +-------------+
              +-------------+
```

The fields table has multiple "fields" such as first_name, last_name etc, that have an id on them, then details would have the appropriate values in them and the Customers table handles the "master" customer information.

What I'm trying to do is get details.field_value, fields.caption WHERE details.customer_id = customers_id AND customers.progress = X and then ORDER it by the id for last_name.

I'm going crazy trying to get this to work, so thought I'd ask here and grab some lunch in the meantime.

Thank you all for the help!

Comment: I don't quite understand your desired output... order _what_ by the id for last name? Could you give an example with desired output?

Comment: Do you want the results in separate rows for each field or in a single row for all fields?

Comment: This is one **epic** lunch break...

Answer (score 1):

I think you can achieve this with an `INNER JOIN` query

```
SELECT c.id, c.caption
FROM customers a
INNER JOIN details b
ON a.customers_ID = b.customers_ID
INNER JOIN fields c
ON b.field_id = c.id
WHERE a.progress = ?
ORDER BY b.last_name ASC
```

Comment: There's no last_name field in details that I can see, I think he may mean that last_name is the field_value for a specific field_id.

Comment: @Joachim he said this is the "simplified schema" so i assumed there are other columns in table details (he said The fields table has multiple "fields" such as first_name, last_name etc). I assume he stored last_name id in something like `last_name` column

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT d.field_value, f.caption
FROM (details d INNER JOIN fields f ON d.field_id = f.id)
INNER JOIN customers c ON d.customer_ID = c.customer_ID
WHERE c.progress = 'X'
ORDER BY f.id
```

Answer (score 0):

One way:

```
select c.customer_ID,
       group_concat(concat(f.caption,':',d.field_value)) Data_Fields,
       max(case f.caption when 'last_name' then d.field_value end) last_name
from customers c
join details d on c.customer_ID = d.c.customer_ID
join fields f on d.field_id = f.id
where c.progress=?
group by c.customer_ID
order by last_name
```